# Row number with lag condition on multiple columns

Tags: pyspark, lag, row-number

I would like to create row number that is partitioned by ACCOUNT, NAME and TYPE.

I tried dense rank and row number. However, I need all initial records that contain changes in any of those columns

```
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
       [
    ('20190910', 'A1', 'Linda', 'b2c'),
    ('20190911', 'A1', 'Tom', 'consultant'),
    ('20190912', 'A1', 'John', 'b2c'),
    ('20190913', 'A1', 'Tom', 'consultant'),
    ('20190914', 'A1', 'Tom', 'consultant'),
    ('20190915', 'A1', 'Linda', 'consultant'),
    ('20190916', 'A1', 'Linda', 'b2c'),
    ('20190917', 'B1', 'John', 'b2c'),
    ('20190916', 'B1', 'John', 'consultant'),
    ('20190910', 'B1', 'Linda', 'b2c'),
    ('20190911', 'B1', 'John', 'b2c'),
    ('20190915', 'C1', 'John', 'consultant'),
    ('20190916', 'C1', 'Linda', 'consultant'),
    ('20190917', 'C1', 'John', 'b2c'),
    ('20190916', 'C1', 'RJohn', 'consultant'),
    ('20190910', 'C1', 'Tom', 'b2c'),
    ('20190911', 'C1', 'John', 'b2c'),
     ],
    ['Event_date', 'account', 'name', 'type']
     )
```

Expected outcome:

| Event_date | account | name | type | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20190910 | A1 | Linda | b2c | 1 |
| 20190911 | A1 | Tom | consultant | 1 |
| 20190912 | A1 | John | b2c | 1 |
| 20190913 | A1 | Tom | consultant | 2 |
| 20190914 | A1 | Tom | consultant | 3 |
| 20190915 | A1 | Linda | consultant | 1 |
| 20190916 | A1 | Linda | b2c | 2 |
| 20190917 | B1 | John | b2c | 1 |
| 20190916 | B1 | John | consultant | 1 |
| 20190910 | B1 | Linda | b2c | 2 |
| 20190911 | B1 | John | b2c | 3 |
| 20190915 | C1 | John | consultant | 1 |
| 20190916 | C1 | Linda | consultant | 1 |
| 20190917 | C1 | John | b2c | 1 |
| 20190916 | C1 | John | consultant | 2 |
| 20190910 | C1 | Tom | b2c | 1 |
| 20190911 | C1 | John | b2c | 2 |

Comment: I assume after partitioning you want to assign row_numbers in the  same order as they appear in the initial dataframe, however this is not possible due to the distributed nature of spark, we can't assume implicit ordering. I would suggest including line number to the initial dataframe and order based on that and generate row_number after partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Window` and partition it by `account`, `name`, `type` and then `row_number` over it.

Example:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("20190910", "A1", "Linda", "b2c"),
        ("20190911", "A1", "Tom", "consultant"),
        ("20190912", "A1", "John", "b2c"),
        ("20190913", "A1", "Tom", "consultant"),
        ("20190914", "A1", "Tom", "consultant"),
        ("20190915", "A1", "Linda", "consultant"),
        ("20190916", "A1", "Linda", "b2c"),
        ("20190917", "B1", "John", "b2c"),
        ("20190916", "B1", "John", "consultant"),
        ("20190910", "B1", "Linda", "b2c"),
        ("20190911", "B1", "John", "b2c"),
        ("20190915", "C1", "John", "consultant"),
        ("20190916", "C1", "Linda", "consultant"),
        ("20190917", "C1", "John", "b2c"),
        ("20190916", "C1", "RJohn", "consultant"),
        ("20190910", "C1", "Tom", "b2c"),
        ("20190911", "C1", "John", "b2c"),
    ],
    ["Event_date", "account", "name", "type"],
)
w = Window.partitionBy("account", "name", "type").orderBy("Event_date")
df = df.withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(w)).orderBy("Event_date")
```

Result:

```
+----------+-------+-----+----------+----------+                                
|Event_date|account|name |type      |row_number|
+----------+-------+-----+----------+----------+
|20190912  |A1     |John |b2c       |1         |
|20190911  |A1     |Tom  |consultant|1         |
|20190913  |A1     |Tom  |consultant|2         |
|20190914  |A1     |Tom  |consultant|3         |
|20190915  |A1     |Linda|consultant|1         |
|20190910  |A1     |Linda|b2c       |1         |
|20190916  |A1     |Linda|b2c       |2         |
|20190911  |B1     |John |b2c       |1         |
|20190916  |B1     |John |consultant|1         |
|20190917  |B1     |John |b2c       |2         |
|20190910  |B1     |Linda|b2c       |1         |
|20190910  |C1     |Tom  |b2c       |1         |
|20190915  |C1     |John |consultant|1         |
|20190916  |C1     |RJohn|consultant|1         |
|20190911  |C1     |John |b2c       |1         |
|20190916  |C1     |Linda|consultant|1         |
|20190917  |C1     |John |b2c       |2         |
+----------+-------+-----+----------+----------+
```

It's not exactly the same as your expected outcome, since it's ordered by `Event_date` and `account`.

> Your expected output doesn't seem to be consistent. Please check the numbers again, especially for `B1`. Also `RJohn` in the input data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something that partition by Account, Name and Type. Then you can order by account followed by event_date.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("20190910", "A1", "Linda", "b2c"),
        ("20190911", "A1", "Tom", "consultant"),
        ("20190912", "A1", "John", "b2c"),
        ("20190913", "A1", "Tom", "consultant"),
        ("20190914", "A1", "Tom", "consultant"),
        ("20190915", "A1", "Linda", "consultant"),
        ("20190916", "A1", "Linda", "b2c"),
        ("20190917", "B1", "John", "b2c"),
        ("20190916", "B1", "John", "consultant"),
        ("20190910", "B1", "Linda", "b2c"),
        ("20190911", "B1", "John", "b2c"),
        ("20190915", "C1", "John", "consultant"),
        ("20190916", "C1", "Linda", "consultant"),
        ("20190917", "C1", "John", "b2c"),
        ("20190916", "C1", "John", "consultant"),
        ("20190910", "C1", "Tom", "b2c"),
        ("20190911", "C1", "John", "b2c"),
    ],
    ["Event_date", "account", "name", "type"],
)
w = Window.partitionBy("account", "name", "type").orderBy("Event_date")
df = df.withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(w)).orderBy("account","Event_date")
```

You will get the output as below :
[image]